# Breaking content from ancestor - XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm doing xml to xml transformation using xslt and I've stuck on one place. The scenario is this,

```
    <doc>
    <tbl>
        <entry>
            <para>aaaa2</para>
            <para>aaaa2</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>zzz</para>
            <para>zzz2</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>bbbb1</para>
            <para>bbbb2</para>
            <tbl>
                <entry>
                    <para>cccc1</para>
                    <para>cccc2</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>ddd1</para>
                    <para>ddd3</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <new-tbl/>
                    <para>eee</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>fff</para>
                </entry>
                <entry>
                    <para>ggg</para>
                </entry>
            </tbl>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>hhh</para>       
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>iii1</para>
            <para>1112</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
</doc>
```

Here is the source xml and it can have `<tbl>` inside other `<tbl>`.

I need to 2 things with this

- If `<tbl>` found within another `<tbl>` break it from the anscetor `<tbl>`
- If `<new-tbl/>` found within `<entry>` create a new `<tbl>` and break it from the anscetor `<tbl>`

Desired output xml,

```
<doc>
    <tbl>
        <entry>
            <para>aaaa2</para>
            <para>aaaa2</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>zzz</para>
            <para>zzz2</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
    <tbl>
        <entry>
            <para>bbbb1</para>
            <para>bbbb2</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
    <tbl>
        <entry>
            <para>cccc1</para>
            <para>cccc2</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>ddd1</para>
            <para>ddd3</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
    <tbl> 
        <entry>
            <new-tbl/>
            <para>eee</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
    <tbl>
        <entry>
            <para>fff</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>ggg</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
    <tbl>
        <entry>
            <para>hhh</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <para>iii1</para>
            <para>1112</para>
        </entry>
    </tbl>
</doc>
```

The first requirement is done by using a for-each loop.

```
<xsl:template match="tbl[descendant::tbl]">
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <tbl>
                <entry>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::tbl)]"/>
                </entry>
            </tbl>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tbl"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

My problem is to extend this code to achieve the second requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we have to have an identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, we have to create named templates that will push tables outside. Such as:

```
<!-- this will move entry nodes with tbl descendants -->
<xsl:template name="move_tbl">
    <xsl:param name="cells"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$cells" group-adjacent="boolean(self::entry[not(descendant::tbl) and not(descendant::new-tbl)])">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <tbl>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </tbl>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-group()[new-tbl]">
                        <tbl>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </tbl>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<!-- this will move tbl nodes outside of entry nodes -->
<xsl:template name="move_tbl_sibling_para">
    <xsl:param name="cells"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="$cells" group-adjacent="boolean(self::para)">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <tbl>
                    <entry>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </entry>
                </tbl>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, the following are template matches for the first `tbl` node, `tbl` nodes with `tbl` ancestor nodes, and `entry` nodes

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="tbl">
            <xsl:call-template name="move_tbl_sibling_para">
                <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="node()[not(self::tbl)]"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tbl"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tbl[ancestor::tbl]">
    <xsl:call-template name="move_tbl">
        <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="doc/tbl">
    <xsl:call-template name="move_tbl">
        <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="node()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

The whole stylesheet is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="entry">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="tbl">
                <xsl:call-template name="move_tbl_sibling_para">
                    <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="node()[not(self::tbl)]"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tbl"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tbl[ancestor::tbl]">
        <xsl:call-template name="move_tbl">
            <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="node()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="doc/tbl">
        <xsl:call-template name="move_tbl">
            <xsl:with-param name="cells" select="node()"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="move_tbl">
        <xsl:param name="cells"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$cells" group-adjacent="boolean(self::entry[not(descendant::tbl) and not(descendant::new-tbl)])">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <tbl>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </tbl>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[new-tbl]">
                            <tbl>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                            </tbl>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="move_tbl_sibling_para">
        <xsl:param name="cells"/>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="$cells" group-adjacent="boolean(self::para)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <tbl>
                        <entry>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </entry>
                    </tbl>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not what I'm looking for. I've edited my source input and desired output for more clarifications. In the final output I need all table to be as a child of <doc> element.